# $cordovaFile removeFile & checkDir error 5 (ENCODING_ERR)

Tags: android, cordova, download, ionic-framework

I am trying to use $cordovaFile to delete files from an Android device. The file to be deleted was downloaded using $cordovaFileTransfer in the following location.

```
ft.download(url, cordova.file.externalDataDirectory + "episodes/" + episodeId + ".mp3",...);
```

Using the file manager on the device I can see that the file is located at `file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.ionicframework.myapp123456/files/episodes/`

`However when I try to use either of the following locations to delete the file I get error code 5 (ENCODING_ERR)

```
$cordovaFile.removeFile("file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.ionicframework.myapp123456/files/episodes/",  "0.mp3")

$cordovaFile.removeFile(cordova.file.externalDataDirectory + "episodes/",  "0.mp3")
```

That same error occurs when I try to use $cordovaFile.checkDir() so I used window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL() instead.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was resolved by using the LocalFileSystem. It is not as elegent as the methods provided by the file plugin, but it works.

```
var uri = cordova.file.externalDataDirectory + "episodes/";

window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(uri, function(dir) {
        dir.getFile(episodeId + ".mp3", { create: false }, function(file) {
            file.remove(successCallback, errorCallback);
        });
}, errorCallback);
```