# Cordova File plugin readAsDataURL not returning file data

Tags: ionic2, cordova-plugins

I am trying without success to use the readAsDataURL function of the Cordova File plugin to get a base64 version of a video file. My code looks like this:

```js
  recordVideo()
  {
    return new Promise(resolve =>
    {
      let options: CaptureVideoOptions = { limit: 1, duration: 2 };
      MediaCapture.captureVideo(options)
        .then(
          (data: MediaFile[]) => {

            console.log('Media: recordVideo: cordova.file.dataDirectory = ' + cordova.file.dataDirectory + ', path = ' + data[0].fullPath.substring(1));

            // Turn the video file into base64
            let base64File = File.readAsDataURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory, data[0].fullPath.substring(1));

            console.log('Media: recordVideo: got video with data = ' + JSON.stringify(data));

            console.log('Media: recordVideo: base64File = ' + JSON.stringify(base64File));

            resolve(data);
          },
          (err: CaptureError) => console.error('ERROR - Media: recordVideo: captureVideo error = ' + err)
        );
    });
  }
```

The output from the first `console.log` shows the values of the parameters passed to the `readAsDataURL`:

```
Media: recordVideo: cordova.file.dataDirectory = file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/764345DC-A77D-43C2-9DF7-CDBE6A0DC372/Library/NoCloud/, path = private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/764345DC-A77D-43C2-9DF7-CDBE6A0DC372/tmp/50713961066__4FD8AF8D-BD36-43A4-99CC-F328ADFD7E38.MOV
```

The second `console.log` shows the data returned by the MediaCapture plugin:

```
Media: recordVideo: got video with data = [{"name":"50713961066__4FD8AF8D-BD36-43A4-99CC-F328ADFD7E38.MOV","localURL":"cdvfile://localhost/temporary/50713961066__4FD8AF8D-BD36-43A4-99CC-F328ADFD7E38.MOV","type":"video/quicktime","lastModified":null,"lastModifiedDate":1485446813000,"size":195589,"start":0,"end":0,"fullPath":"/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/764345DC-A77D-43C2-9DF7-CDBE6A0DC372/tmp/50713961066__4FD8AF8D-BD36-43A4-99CC-F328ADFD7E38.MOV"}]
```

The last `console.log` shows the value returned by the `readAsDataURL`:

```
Media: recordVideo: base64File = {"__zone_symbol__state":null,"__zone_symbol__value":[]}
```

There is next to no documentation on using this (that I can find).

Comment: Actually ionic2-native, File.readAsDataURL returns promise. Have you tried File.readAsDataURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory, data[0].fullPath.substring(1)).then((result) => { console.log(result); }

Comment: Thanks for that I can now see why it isn't working as I am catching the errors. If I try using the fullPath returned by captureVideo I get the error 'cannot have a leading /'. If I remove the slash from the fullPath I get the error NOT_FOUND'. If I pass the localURL I get the error 'ENCODING_ERR'. Any ideas on how I can get this to work?

Comment: Did you check whether the path you are looking for the file is correct? Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35388817/cordovafile-removefile-checkdir-error-5-encoding-err as well.. It might help you

Comment: The path is returned by the MediaCapture.captureVideo so it must be correct.

Comment: Any ideas? I am at a loss here.

Comment: From your console log, i could see the path for cordova.file.datadirectory and your data path are almost similar. ReadUsDataURL requires path and filename as variable. May be that is the reason you are getting "NOT Found" err. Try using the   File.readAsDataURL(data[0].fullPath.substring(0,str.lastIndexOf("/")), data[0].name).then(file => {
    this.base64File = file;
   };

Comment: If you still receive "NOT_Found" err, adjust your path as   
var path = "file://"+data[0].fullPath.substring(7,str.lastIndexOf("/"));
  File.readAsDataURL(path, data[0].name).then(file => {
    this.base64File = file;
   };

Comment: Excellent. The last of those worked for me substituting 'data[0].fullPath' for 'str'. Can't thank you enough for your help!

Comment: thats super :).. Glad to help. i will add it in answer so that it may help others looking for it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function readAsDataURL gets path and filename as parameters and returns a promise. The usage is

```
File.readAsDataURL("path_to_the_FileName", "Filename").then(result => {
  this.base64File = result;
});
```

As per the console log, the filename and full path to the filename are obtained from data (promise returned from MediaCapture.captureVideo).

So you can use it as below

```
var path = "file://"+data[0].fullPath.substring(7,data[0].fullPath.lastIndexOf("/"))‌​; 
File.readAsDataURL(path, data[0].name).then(result => { 
  this.base64File = result;
}
```

Comment: You need to change the str.lastIndexOf to data[0].fullPath.lastIndexOf.

Comment: yep.. Forgot to change it. Changed now :)

Answer (score 3):

If issue is this that **File.readAsDataURL** is not returning response nor catching error then move the cordova.js after vendor.js script (in the index.html). I was facing this issue in my ionic 3 app. I solved this from this link [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/issues/2117).

Comment: Thanks. How on earth did you figure out that this could be the problem? I definitely think that Ionic isn't production ready and even totally a trash.

Comment: I am using ionic 5 and there are no `cordova.js` nor `vendor.js` in the `index.html`